# Split first name(s) from last name in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I wanted to separate the last name in a cell from any and all first/middle names.

EG:

```
"Greg Smith"
"Andy H K Anderson"
"Tony & Amanda Ferguson"
```

Becomes

```
Greg          | Smith
Andy H K      | Anderson
Tony & Amanda | Ferguson
```

Couldn't find an answer here or on any other site. but I did manage to write my own formula that I wanted to share in case others run into this same problem. And perhaps someone else could make a better version.

FIRST NAME(S):

```
=LEFT(A2,MINUS(LEN(A2),LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A2," "),0,COUNTA(SPLIT(A2," "))))))
```

LAST NAME:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2," "),0,COUNTA(SPLIT(A2," ")))
```

Comment: That's not the way this site works. This is a question and answer site, which means there must be a question asked in this space, and an answer posted in the space below provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/hep/self-answer). You can't just post them both in the question space.

Comment: Your formula probably fails on "Camilla Parker Bowles". There is no foolproof way to split any name into "first" and "last". But you might get a high percentage for your part of the world.

Comment: I don't think there's a single formula you can use to determine one's first and last name out of a string. You even can't be sure if somebody *has* a distinction of first and last name. See [a blog post about falsehood programmer beliefs](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person) about mononyms

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way (using a single array formula) would be to use regexextract

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), regexextract(A2:A, "(.+)\s([^\s]+)$"),))
```

The first capturing group (.+) extracts

- every character .+
- before the last space \s (in a 'greedy' way),

the second capturing group ([^\s]+) extracts

- everything after the last space [^\s]+
- to the end of the string $.